# Sublime Text: Find and remove all duplicates

Tags: string, sublimetext2

I have a file with the following:

```
a
b
b
c
```

And I need to find all duplicates and remove them, so it should be like this:

```
a
c
```

The command "edit > permute lines > unique" wouldn't delete all the occurrences. Any suggestions? Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Try: "edit -> sort lines" then "edit -> permute lines -> unique"

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, just give me an alphabetical ordered list

Answer (score 2):

Select some text and press Ctrl + D to add more instances.
Then press delete to remove.
Read more feature at [Sublime text doc](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/editing/editing.html#multiple-selections)

Comment: thank you! isn't there a way to automate this process within sublime?

Comment: I don't know ( i don't think so ) if Sublime text gives natively this feature. Instead, you can record a macro or create your own plug-in ( python language ). First step for these action are well documented on the doc (see link ina bove post ).